# using iosMath and SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a small math learning application.

So I installed iosMath, but using SwiftUI I don't know how to declare a MTMathUILabel.

Maybe someone has a lead to help me?

I tried this but got the following error message: "Constant'label' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected".

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import iosMath

struct MyViewMath : View {

    let label = MTMathUILabel().latex="\\sum"

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                View1()
                Text("\(label)")
                View2()
            }


        }
    }
}

// My view code bellow
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you show the solution code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MTMathUILabel` is a `UIView` subclass, so you cannot use it directly in a SwiftUI `View`. Instead, you need to create a new type that conforms to `UIViewRepresentable` to wrap the `MTMathUILabel`. Tanu Singhal explains the process in detail in [WWDC 2019 Session 231: Integrating SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/231/).